# VR, does the "motion to photon" latency changes with speed of rotation of the headset?

Tags: performance, virtual-reality

Motion-to-Photon latency is the time needed for a user movement to be fully reflected on a display screen. 
A high motion-to-photon latency makes a poor virtual reality experience (motion sickness and nausea). 
Does the "motion to photon" latency changes with speed of rotation of the headset?

Comment: Did my response answer your question? If so please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a programming question.

The motion-to-photon latency can vary depending on the render time. If you use [asynchronous timewarp](https://developer.oculus.com/blog/asynchronous-timewarp-examined/) it will always be (or rather should always be) constant. It will re-render the previous frame (taking into consideration the head motion) if the new frame wasn't ready in time.

So, generally the answer is **no**, it does not have anything to do with the rotation speed of your head.